# Sidebar didnt show in IE 7 and 8

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Hi I have problem with "sidebar"  ( green in left on page... with text "Novinky a nepřehlédněte")

My problem is: In Firefox, g. Chrome, etc... works good, but in IE 7 and 8 didn't show it.

Page: http://www.vivafitnes.cz/

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I can see it in IE8, but you have some script conflict that prevents IE7 to load. You have too many scripts and instances of the same script, so very hard to say which one is the culprit, but I'd bet it is

```
var obj = $("body");
```

which should be

```
var obj = $('body');
```